# Applying GraphQL directives to extended Objects

Tags: javascript, graphql, directive, apollo-server

I implemented a directive as defined here - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/creating-directives/#enforcing-access-permissions

I noticed that if I applied @auth to my `extend type Query` / `Mutation`, visitor method `visitObject` would not be called but if applied to a non-extended object, it would be called. I couldn't find any documentation referring to this limitation. Is there a way to apply directives to extend type OBJECT ?